# Delete index at array in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I got this data in my document:

[image]

I want to delete index 0. How do I do this? This should do the trick I thought:

```
    db.collection("data").document("free").updateData(["deleteme.deletemee.0" : FieldValue.delete()]) { (errr) in
        print(errr)
    }
```

But the errr prints nil, and nothing is removed. When getting the document I noticed something strange about the data when using this code:

```
    db.collection("data").document("free").getDocument { (doc, err) in
        guard let _doc = doc,
            doc?.exists ?? false else{ return }
        print(_doc.data())
    }
```

This prints out:

```
["deleteme": {
    deletemee =     (
        1 //this is the value for the key, but where is my key?! :(
    );
}]
```

I cannot see the key, where is it? How to delete something at an index in Firestore? Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Array operations have finally been supported. Deletion, addition, etc. are supported **via the value (not the index)** now:[image: See this]

At the moment, there are a few bugs at the moment though as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51772516/firestore-bug-in-index-creation-utility-involving-array-fields/51797638#51797638) one I encountered.

The dev blog [here:](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html)

Comment: This MUST be the answer now.

Comment: @Sampath yea times have changed, I made this answer now the accepted answer

Comment: In case if values are `double`, then `arrayRemove` needs to match the value up to last precision : (

Answer (score 5):

It is not currently possible to modify individual elements of an array stored in Cloud Firestore.

If you stored the data as a map (the keys dont matter) like this:

```
{
  name: "sam",
  things: {
    one: "value",
    two: "value"
  }
}
```

Then you can delete individual elements like this:

```
// Delete the things.one data
db.collection("whatever").document("whatever").updateData([
    "things.one": FieldValue.delete(),
]) { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error updating document: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Document successfully updated")
    }
}
```

Now the data will look like this:

```
{
  name: "sam",
  things: {
    two: "value"
  }
}
```

Comment: >:( hmm ok so arrays are pretty useless at this time since they can not be changed...

Comment: Yes right now they're not terribly useful, but these are just Beta limitations and in the future we will have better support for arrays / array queries.

Answer (score -1):

```
export const deleteArrayIndex = (collectionName, id, index) => {
    db.collection(collectionName).doc(id).update(
        { [index]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete() }
    ).then(function () {
        console.log(index + "  is deleted");
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Danish. Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.