# Firestore: Bug in Index creation utility involving array fields

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Was trying out firestore array-contains feature:

I have a `projects` collection having an array field, `projectUsers`

Query:

```
 db.collection('projects')
  .where(`deleted`, '==', false)
  .orderBy('lastUpdate','desc')
  .where('projectUsers', 'array-contains', '56xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxc9')
  .get()
  .then(function (doc) {

    ....
    ....
 })
```

Firestore promptly gave me the index creation link that directed me to this:
[image: index creation screen]

When I click on the `Create index` button, nothing happens! Console shows the following error:

```
code: 400
message: "Unknown Index field mode: MODE_UNSPECIFIED"
status: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
```

Comment: Thanks for finding a bug in the index creation wizard. Can you report the exact steps to reproduce [in a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/)?

Comment: Have done that. Btw, does the feature cover not just arrays containing plain strings too? That is, say a map like, `{"user":"Jon", "role": "admin"}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got this reply from google:

> Thank you for the information provided. We have fixed this issue, it will be pushed by the end of next week. If you continue experiencing this issue after that, please let us know.